# Addition of powdered peanut butter

Tags: beer

I want to add peanut Butter to my batch How much powdered peanut butter can I add to a 5 gallon batch?

Comment: What sort of beer are you making? What's the starting gravity? What sort of grains or extract are you brewing from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a recipe for peanut butter beer in my book.  We recommend 12 oz. of PB2 powder, dissolved in 6 oz. of 150 proof spirits.  Let that sit for a few days, then put it in a keg and rack the beer onto it.  Let it cold crash for a week, then rack the beer off the slurry into a fresh keg.

Comment: It is a brown ale! Would it be a problem if I added the Powder(PB2) when I transferred it to the secondary?

Comment: I can only recommend the technique I wrote about above.  I don't know how any other method would work.