# Formulating a recipe

Tags: recipe-formulation, clone-recipe

Can anyone guess at how to build a clone recipe? Its for Duclaws [Sweet Baby Jesus](http://duclaw.com/beer/sweet-baby-jesus/#sthash.ypwRgVp1.dpuf), a friend requested a clone. Their website only says it's a Black beer, a Chocolate Peanut Butter Porter. Their website only lists the types of grains and hops, but not the amounts. I'm guessing there would be various adjuncts, probably both in the boil and "dry hopping" with the coffee (I've done dry coffee grounds before). I'm not sure where the peanut butter flavor would come from though. I can probably guess at the hops, but the grains is where I'd need help, and the peanut butter, that is a mystery to me.

From the website

> ...jet black in color with a tan, rocky head, full body and creamy,
>   luxurious mouthfeel. Its lightly sweet, malty flavor is accented by
>   rich flavors of chocolate, coffee and peanut butter, and balanced by a
>   subtle hop character and moderate 6.5% abv. Sweet Baby Jesus finishes
>   smooth, dry, and roasty with lingering notes of chocolate and peanut
>   butter...

HOPS

- Fuggle
- Goldings

GRAINS

- Pale Malt
- Chocolate Malt
- Crystal Malt
- Munich Malt
- Brown Malt
- Roasted Barley

ABV

- 6.6%

IBU

- 33

<sub>An aside, we have tags for this type of post, so hopefully it's still on topic. If not, I can get rid of it.</sub>

<sub>Another aside, has anyone even tried this beer? Is it worth cloning?</sub>

Comment: <sub>Insert *aside* here</sub>. The mark-up shows in comments, but will format as subscript in a question or answer.

Comment: I know homebrewers who have used peanut butter powder to add flavor. It is basically peanut butter with all of the oil removed. IDK if it went into the boil or secondary.

Comment: I think what would be useful for this is a guide on typical proportions of different grains based on the base malt (pale) for this type of beer if there is such a thing?

Comment: I'd be looking at brewtoad.com for other peanut butter porter recipes and using one of those as a starting point.  Like this one :https://www.brewtoad.com/recipes/peanut-butter-porter-18.  Have a play with the hopping schedule to tweak the IBU's and color and work in the other hop your source beer has.  Brew, try, tweak, repeat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the IBU and ABV you are looking for. To get the mouth feel you will have to play around with mash-in temps to try get the right proportions of un-fermentable sugars out.

```
4.5 kg    10lb Pale 2-Row (UK)              Any Mash    38  2 °L
0.45 kg    1lb  Chocolate (US)              Any Mash    29  350 °L
0.45 kg    1lb  Caramel/Crystal 60L (US)    Any Mash    34  60 °L
0.23 kg  1/2lb CaraMunich II (DE)           Any Mash    34  46 °L
0.23 kg  1/2lb CaraBrown (US)               Any Mash    34  55 °L
0.1 kg   1/4lb Roasted Barley (US)          Any Mash    33  300 °L
Hops

Amount  Hop Time    Use Form    AA
20.0 g  Golding (US)    60 min  Boil    Pellet  4.5%
20.0 g  Fuggle (US)     60 min  Boil    Pellet  4.8%
20.0 g  Golding (US)    20 min  Boil    Pellet  4.5%
20.0 g  Fuggle (US)     20 min  Boil    Pellet  4.8%
10.0 g  Golding (US)     5 min  Boil    Pellet  4.5%
10.0 g  Fuggle (US)      5 min  Boil    Pellet  4.8%

Yeasts

Safale US-05    Fermentis US-05 85.5%

Stats

Batch & Boil

Batch Size
23.0 L ~5gal
Boil Time
90 min
Properties

OG: 1.059
FG: 1.009 
IBU: 32
ABV: 6.6% 
Color: 32 SRM
Balance: 0.70 – Bitter
```

I'd take the peanut powdering advice from the brewtoad link nemmy provided:

1 lb. PB2 Powdered Peanut Butter - 7 days secondary

1 lb. PB2 Powdered Chocolate Peanut Butter - 7 days secondary

Comment: Thanks for that! But that seems like a lot of PB2. I think I'll go with [Denny's answer](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/11916/3925) for that part.

Comment: Fair point it does seem like a serious amount.